# SQL Insert missing values from Lookup table to transaction table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table `EmpJob` listing Employee, Job done and number of times the Job was done (columns: EmpID, JobID, Total). I have another Lookup table `Jobs` that lists all jobs (columns: JobID, JobDesc). An Employee may not do all jobs. My requirement is to show all employees showing all Jobs with Count for Jobs-not-done as zero.
I am clueless on this. I tried using `IF EXISTS` clause or `NOT EXISTS` in `WHERE` clause but that's not giving me the right results.
Here's an example:
`Jobs` table:

```
JobID | JobDesc
---------------
 1    | Job1
 2    | Job2
 3    | Job3
```

`EmpJob` table:

```
EmpID | JobID | Total
 Emp1 |     1 | 3
 Emp1 |     3 | 5
 Emp2 |     2 | 6
```

The result should be `3 Jobs x 2 Employees = 6 records` as

```
Emp1 | Job1 | 3
Emp1 | Job2 | 0
Emp1 | Job3 | 5
Emp2 | Job1 | 0
Emp2 | Job2 | 6
Emp2 | Job3 | 0
```

Can anybody suggest a query? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch of a strategy to follow:

- get set of employees:

  ```
  select distinct EmpID from EmpJob // query1
  ```

  (if you have no other source of employees)
- get cross-product of jobs and employees:

  ```
  select EmpID,JobID,0 as Total from <query1> outer join Jobs // query2
  ```
- do a union of known counts and 0-counts:

  ```
  select EmpID,JobID,Total from EmpJob union <query2> // query3
  ```
- sum up the totals of every (employee,job) group

  ```
  select EmpID,JobID,sum(Total) from <query3> group by EmpID,JobID
  ```

Putting the pieces together gives you the result:

```
select EmpID, JobID, sum(Total) as Total from (
  (select EmpID, JobID, 0 as Total from Jobs outer join (select distinct EmpID from EmpJob))
  union
  (select EmpID, JobID, Total from EmpJob)
) group by EmpID, JobID
order by EmpID, JobID
```

Comment: With Left Outer Join on Jobs you get EmpID and JobID as NULLS for 0 Total rows.